# Encoding of the web page

Tags: encoding

I have used a free template and used it as a master page in the visual web developer.
Each time I close the master page file and reopen it it will ask me for the encoding of the web page. The title is "Choose an encoding", and body is "Visual web developer was unable to determine the encoding of this file. Please choose an encoding from the list box below".
How can I fix this? How can I save the file with UTF-8 encoding from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a tag like this inside the `<head>` element:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

That's how you identify the encoding to browsers. Not sure about the editor you're using.