# Special characters in output are like �

Tags: python, encoding, character

I have some .txt files which included Turkish characters. I prepared a HTML code and wanna include texts which are in my txt files. The processes are successful but the html files which are made by python have character problems(special characters seems like this: �)

I have tried add u before strings in python code but it did not work.

txt files are made by python. actually they are my blog entries I got them using urrlib. Moreover, they have not character problems

thank you for your answers.

Comment: Is your HTML file's encoding set correctly?

Comment: [This posting shows how to set it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336448/).

Comment: This is an encoding problem and with this much info, answers will likely be too broad to be helpful. Make sure that python is outputting with a popular encoding such as `UTF-8` and adjust your server http headers / html page meta-tags accordingly. You will find plenty of info about those subjects in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

When you serve the content to a web browser, you need to tell it what encoding the file is in. Ideally, you should send a `Content-type:` HTTP header in the response with something like `text/plain; charset=utf-8`, where "utf-8" is replaced by whatever encoding you're actually using if it's not utf-8.

Your browser may also need to be set to use a unicode-aware font for displaying text files; if it uses a font that doesn't have the necessary glyphs, obviously it can't display them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't a Python question.  Have you [specified the document's character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Specifying_the_document.27s_character_encoding)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply you html with something like the next:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Replace `UTF-8` with encoding used in .txt file.